# Command to open pdf file when editing a latex document

Tags: autocmd, filetype-tex, shell

I have this command to open the pdf created by a latex document:

```
autocmd FileType tex nnoremap <leader>p :silent !open $(echo "%:p" \| sed s/.tex/.pdf/g)<CR>
```

which works, but I'd like to make 2 modifications:

1. the command should be executed silently, without appearing on the command line;
2. if there is no pdf document associated with the tex file, I'd like to display an error message saying something like 'No pdf file...'

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the mapping silently, without the command appearing in the command-line, you should use the [`<silent>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-silent) modifier to `nnoremap`.

To check that the file exists, you can use the [`filereadable()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#filereadable%28%29) function.

You'll have to generate the PDF filename within Vim, but that shouldn't be hard, by using the additional `:r` modifier to remove the extension. You'll also need `expand()` to perform that expansion.

It's easier to use a separate function for the action, so you don't need to escape so many special characters.

One more note is that for a filetype mapping, you probably want to create a [local mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-local) on the buffers with TeX files only. You might also want to use the [`<LocalLeader>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3CLocalLeader%3E) prefix.

When running the external shell command, you'll want to use `shellescape()` to ensure the file name is safe and that you can properly handle paths with spaces.

Putting it all together:

```
function! OpenPdf() abort
  let fname = expand('%:p:r').'.pdf'
  if filereadable(fname)
    execute 'silent !open '.shellescape(fname, 1)
  else
    echohl ErrorMsg
    echomsg 'No pdf file "'.fname.'"'
    echohl None
  endif
endfunction

augroup tex_pdf
  au!
  au FileType tex nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <LocalLeader>p :<C-U>call OpenPdf()<CR>
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great if the pdf file exists, but if it doesn't exist I don't just get the error message, I also get a line that says `Error detected while processing function OpenPdf:`, followed by the line on which the error occurs `line    5:`, then the error msg I actually want, and then a confirmation dialog `Press ENTER or type command to continue`. [Here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/yT8qhJP) of what I see. How can I have the error message and nothing else?

Comment: @noibe Just drop the `abort` on the definition of the function. I'll update the answer to do that. I guess that's exactly what you specified, right?

Comment: Even after dropping `abort` the output is the same, nothing's changed.

Comment: @noibe Ah, indeed! Let's use `echohl` instead. Updating again.

Comment: Great, it works now!